# Replace matching regex in a file with custom word

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am trying to replace version number (like `00.00.00-00`) in a file with actual version number in shell.

For this I use the following command:

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]*\.+[0-9]*\.+[0-9]*\-+[0-9]*/MyNewVersion/g' file.txt
```

Example of the file.txt:

```
Some text Bla Bla Bla-00.00.00-00.x86_SomeOtherInterestingThings
```

Unfortunately it does not give me desired result.
Any advice?

Comment: Remove all `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you would need `-r` flag in order to mark the pattern as a regular expression. Next, you would need to move the quantifier `+` next to the number ranges, so I believe you should be using this command:

```
sed -i -r 's/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+/MyNewVersion/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Well, even without `-r` that would be parsed as a regex, `-r` will make it be parsed as  a POSIX ERE pattern (where `+` quantifier does not need escaping, in BRE POSIX, in GNU `sed`, `+` can be used if escaped). No need to escape `-`, BTW.

Comment: Removed backslash before `-`

Answer (score 0):

based on the example input/pattern, this line should help:

```
sed 's/[-0-9.]\+\([.]x86_\)/-NEW\1/'
```